# How to test only one part of method which part's test is written in test class with spock

Tags: java, unit-testing, groovy, spock

I have sign up method in service class and I try to write unit test for success case for prevent dublicate email

```
public void signUp(UserDTO userDTO) {
        logger.info("ActionLog.Sign up user.Start");
        Optional<UserEntity> checkedEmail = userRepository.findByEmail(userDTO.getEmail());
        System.out.println(checkedEmail);
        if (checkedEmail.isPresent()) {
            System.out.println("check email: "+checkedEmail);
            logger.error("ActionLog.WrongDataException.Thrown");
            throw new WrongDataException("This email already exists");
        }

        String password = new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(userDTO.getPassword());
        UserEntity customerEntity = UserEntity
                .builder()
                .name(userDTO.getName())
                .surname(userDTO.getSurname())
                .username(userDTO.getEmail())
                .email(userDTO.getEmail())
                .password(password)
                .role(Role.ROLE_USER)
                .build();

        userRepository.save(customerEntity);
        logger.info("ActionLog.Sign up user.Stop.Success");

    }
```

And this is my test class

```
class UserServiceImplTest extends Specification {

    UserRepository userRepository
    AuthenticationServiceImpl authenticationService
    UserServiceImpl userService

    def setup() {
        userRepository = Mock()
        authenticationService = Mock()
        userService = new UserServiceImpl(userRepository, authenticationService)
    }

    def "doesn't throw exception if email doesn't exist in database"() {

        given:
        def userDto = new UserDTO()
        def entity = new Optional<UserEntity>()
        userDto.setEmail("example@mail.ru")
        1 * userRepository.findByEmail(userDto.getEmail()) >> entity
        1 * entity.isPresent() >> false

        when: "send dto object to service "
        userService.signUp(userDto)


        then: ""
        notThrown(WrongDataException)
    }


}
```

test is failed , because it gives me NPE for ByCryptPasswordEncoder:
but I don't write integration test and I have to test only dublicate email success and fail cases

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(BCryptPasswordEncoder.java:108)
    at az.gdg.msauth.service.impl.UserServiceImpl.signUp(UserServiceImpl.java:41)
    at az.gdg.msauth.service.UserServiceImplTest.doesn't throw exception if email doesn't exist in database(UserServiceImplTest.groovy:35)
```

But, I comment these in service class

```
String password = new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(userDTO.getPassword());
        UserEntity customerEntity = UserEntity
                .builder()
                .name(userDTO.getName())
                .surname(userDTO.getSurname())
                .username(userDTO.getEmail())
                .email(userDTO.getEmail())
                .password(password)
                .role(Role.ROLE_USER)
                .build();

        userRepository.save(customerEntity);
```

It gives me

```
Too few invocations for:

1 * entity.isPresent() >> false   (0 invocations)

Unmatched invocations (ordered by similarity):

None


Too few invocations for:

1 * entity.isPresent() >> false   (0 invocations)

Unmatched invocations (ordered by similarity):

None
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You need to introduce a level of abstract that makes you in control for new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode. And then use dependecy injection to be able to provide a mock during unit test, and the real implementation for production code. Does BCryptPasswordEncoder implement an Interface?

Comment: Or surely, if you're going to do `1 * entity.isPresent() >> false`, you need to give the entity a password for the Encoder to encode?

Comment: I am new on spock framework. I want to test only if block's success and fail cases, not password encoder. Because it is belonged to spring.Unfortunately, When test starts , it reads all codes from up do down in service , when reaches to encoder it throws exception . My question is , how I can test only if block

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) article in order to learn how to ask good questions and why an MCVE is so valuable if you want to get a good answer. Thank you.

Comment: As for your `NullPointerException`, without the MCVE I can only speculate that `userDTO.getPassword()` is `null` because in your test you forgot to initialise the password, as Tim said already.

Comment: You cannot test only part of a method and then magically stop the method from executing. What you need to do instead is make sure the method runs as expected by setting up the subject under test and its dependencies (other objects used by it) correspondingly. This is not specific to Spock, these are unit testing basics. Don't worry, we all want to help you and know that starting with a new topic can be overwhelming. :-) P.S.: If you feel the need to test part of a method, maybe you method does too much and ought to be split into smaller methods, each doing a dedicated, smaller job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I looked at your code some more and created lots of dummy classes locally in order to make it compile and run, trying to figure out what your use case is. Actually you should have shown in your [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but I think I have an idea now. *(Thanks to COVID-19 I was bored because there was no place to go and meet friends today.)*

I see two immediate problems:

1. You cannot define an interaction `1 * entity.isPresent() >> false` because your `entity` is not a mock or spy. Furthermore, you use a private constructor for `Optional` in order to initialise `entity`, which is also ugly and would not work outside of Groovy. Furthermore, it is not necessary to check that `isPresent()` was called on the optional object, only made sure that the method call returns `false`. This can be achieved much easier by just writing `def entity = Optional.empty()` and deleting the interaction instead.
2. As I said in a comment, you can get rid of the `NullPointerException` for the encryptor call by just making sure that the DTO has a password set via `userDto.setPassword("pw")` or similar. Your test would then look like this:

```groovy
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q60884910

import spock.lang.Specification

class UserServiceImplTest extends Specification {
  UserRepository userRepository
  AuthenticationServiceImpl authenticationService
  UserServiceImpl userService

  def setup() {
    userRepository = Mock()
    authenticationService = Mock()
    userService = new UserServiceImpl(userRepository, authenticationService)
  }

  def "doesn't throw exception if email doesn't exist in database"() {
    given:
    def userDto = new UserDTO()
    def entity = Optional.empty()
    userDto.setEmail("example@mail.ru")
    userDto.setPassword("pw")
    1 * userRepository.findByEmail(userDto.getEmail()) >> entity
//    1 * entity.isPresent() >> false

    when: "send dto object to service "
    userService.signUp(userDto)

    then: ""
    notThrown(WrongDataException)
  }

}
```

I also think it is not necessary to check that `userRepository.findByEmail(..)` is actually called and that it is called with a specific parameter. I think this is over-specification for a unit test. You would have to adjust it when changing the internal implementation of the method under test. I think here it should be enough to just specify the stub result. If you also reorganise the code a bit, the test looks like this:

```groovy
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q60884910

import spock.lang.Specification

class UserServiceImplTest extends Specification {
   def userRepository = Stub(UserRepository)
   def authenticationService = Stub(AuthenticationServiceImpl)
   def userService = new UserServiceImpl(userRepository, authenticationService)

  def "doesn't throw exception if email doesn't exist in database"() {
    given: "a user DTO"
    def userDto = new UserDTO()
    userDto.email = "example@mail.ru"
    userDto.password = "pw"

    and: "a user repository not finding any user by e-mail"
    userRepository.findByEmail(_) >> Optional.empty()

    when: "signing up a new user"
    userService.signUp(userDto)

    then: "no duplicate e-mail address exception is thrown"
    notThrown WrongDataException
  }
}
```

Please note that I changed `Mock()` to `Stub()` because we do not check any interactions (number of calls) anymore. If you feel you need this for `userRepository`, you can revert it to be a mock with an `1 * ...` interaction again.

P.S.: I still think your method under test would profit from refactoring it into smaller methods which then you can easily stub and/or test separately. Dependency injection for the `BCryptPasswordEncoder` or factoring out the password check into a separate method might also be helpful if you like to mock/stub the encoder or its result for some tests.

Comment: Sir,Thanks a lot for clear explanation.It is solved my problem and I understood what I should do